Set of all base n Integers represented with n alphanumeric characters contain the set of all 'texts' possible with that set of characters?
Does the set of all base n Integers represented with n alphanumeric characters contain the set of all 'texts' possible with that set of characters?
eg:
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, AA, AB, AC, AD... BA, BB, BC, BD, BE, BF, BG, BH, BI, ... ZA, ZB, ZC, ZD, ZE, ZF, ZG, ZH, ZI, ZJ, ZK, ZL, ZM, ZN, ZO, ZP, ZQ, ZR, ZS....AAA, AAB, AAC,...WORD, WORE, WORF,...

Do "texts" include spaces between words and punctuation?

yes! My example tries to show a reduced case example for say, n=26 but the character set should include al necessary characters and breaks for any given language.

The answer is yes. If every character in the alphabet has a distinct value, then any string of characters must map to a positive integer using $\overline{a_k \ldots a_1 a_0} = a_k n^k + \ldots + a_1 n + a_0$ (assuming there are $n$ characters). Additionally, you can prove that each integer has a unique representation in this base (i.e. if you have two equal representations $\overline{a_k \ldots a_1 a_0} = \overline{b_j \ldots b_1 b_0}$ it must be that $a_0 = b_0$ and so forth for all the corresponding digits).
